On the Papal Bull (Sanctissimus Dominus Noster) of Urban VIII
In the Papal Bull, Sanctissimus Dominus Noster, of March 13, 1625, Pope Urban VIII instructed Catholics not to venerate the deceased or represent them in the manner of Saints without the sanction of the Catholic Church.
I have not located a copy of this letter.
I would like to read it, as well as determine what are the penalties on those who violate its dictates.
QUESTION: (i) Where may I obtain (preferably online) a copy of the document; and, (ii) What are the penalties imposed for its violation?
Thank you.

Where did you hear about this supposed bull? It didn't give a citation to the original source?

@Geremia See, for example, Policy on Private Revelation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Urban_VIII#:~:text=In%20the%20papal%20bull%20Sanctissimus,in%20this%20book..."

@Geremia I wanted to locate the papal document where honoring people as Saints (without Church approval) is spelled out and proscribed. (I am quote certain that it was promulgated by Urban VIII.) The motivation is here: The "Feast Day" of Fr. Andre Coindre who is not only not a canonized Saint, but his cause to my knowledge has never been opened.  https://www.brothermartin.com/happy-feast-day-of-father-andre-coindre/

@Geremia Regarding Fr. Andre Coindre, I believe it would very difficult to open his cause because of the suspicious manner in which he died---possible (or, probable) suicide.

It would be found in:

Bullarum Diplomatum et Privilegiorum Sanctorum Romanorum Pontificum (1868) tome 13, Urbanus VIII, 1623-1628.

However, I cannot locate it. A Sanctissimus Dominus Noster (3 October 1625) on p. 371 is about censorship of books. Nothing is listed for 13 March 1625, which would be between the 12 March 1625 and 15 March 1625 bulls on p. 298.

Many thanks for your research and for providing this information.

I emailed Vatican archive (archivio@aav.va) the question "Is it possible to get a digital copy of a Papal Bull, Sanctissimus Dominus Noster, given in March 13, 1625, by Pope Urban VIII?" and was told:

the document of your interest is not a papal bull, but a decree of the Congregation of Inquisition

Then attached was 73 page pdf. As I cannot attach a PDF to an answer I searched google books and I got a few similar hits that start the same (but these are in color, the one I was sent was black and white). All of these are not in english and so I have not 100% verified the contents but this might get you closer to an actual document.

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Decreta_seruanda_in_canonizatione_beatif/4CLo629udK4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=decreta+Inquifitionis+edita+fub+diebus+13+Martij+%26+OCtobris+1625&pg=PA2&printsec=frontcover
https://www.google.com/books/edition/Decreta_et_ordo_conficiendi_processus_in/99Zml5fKMesC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=decreta+Inquifitionis+edita+fub+diebus+13+Martij+%26+OCtobris+1625&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover
https://www.google.com/books/edition/VRBANI_VIII_PONTIFICIS_OPTIMI_MAXIMI_DEC/3ixoAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=decreta+Inquifitionis+edita+fub+diebus+13+Martij+%26+OCtobris+1625&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover
https://www.google.com/books/edition/Vrbani_8_pontifici_optimi_maximi_Decreta/pXSu5UKrztcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=decreta+Inquifitionis+edita+fub+diebus+13+Martij+%26+OCtobris+1625&pg=PA2&printsec=frontcover


Trying to put in titles, but not successfully. For some reason it is not cooperating.
